# Is there no simple way to make a deep of lists in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried `List.from` and `[...orginalObject]`, but neither does a deep copy. In both cases it's clearly just copying the references. Which means if I change any data in the list in which I copied the data, the original data gets changed too.

It seems to me that the only way to do a `for` loop and define each of the entries the copied list with a `new` operator and the data from each of corresponding entries from the original list. Something as shown in the following image.

[image]

Seems like quite a tedious approach. Is there any simpler approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla Dart, not really, since this would require the ability to copy the leaf objects, and there is no way for the language to know how to do that for arbitrary objects.

However, the `built_value` and `built_collection` packages may solve your issue. One of their main features is deep immutability. First, you write your classes like this:

```dart
class Item {
    final String foo;
    final int bar;
    
    Item(this.foo, this.bar);
}

// becomes

part 'item.g.dart';

abstract class Item extends Built<Item, ItemBuilder> {
    Item._();
    factory Item([void Function(ItemBuilder) updates]) = _$Item;
    // boilerplate, can use tooling to auto-generate

    String get foo;
    int get bar;
}
```

This lets you create an immutable object using a mutable `Builder` and then finalizing it, e.g.:

```dart
final item1 = Item((b) {
    // here b is an ItemBuilder, the mutable version of Item
    b.foo = 'Hello';
    b.bar = 123;
});

final item2 = item1.rebuild((b) => b.foo = 'New Value');  // Item(foo: 'New Value', bar: 123)
```

You can then use `built_collection` to work with deeply immuatble collections of built values, e.g.:

```
final list = BuiltList<Item>([item1, item2, item3]);

final deepCopy = list.rebuild((b) {});  // rebuild with no changes

final withNewElement = list.rebuild((b) => b.add(item4));
```

The important thing with all of these is that they are all immutable, and are "value objects", meaning (among other things) that they are considered equal if all their corresponding values are equal. You can consider each `rebuild` call to be returning you a brand new list with all the values copied over.

In fact, the library is smart enough to only create new objects for values that have actually changed, but because it is immutable, it acts like a deep copy, without the potential performance costs.

The main downside with these libraries is that they rely on code generation, so it requires a bit more setup than just putting it in your `dependencies`. In return, you get a lot of useful features in addition to having deeply immutable objects (like json serialization, null checking in pre-null-safety code, `@memoized` to cache results of expensive computations`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Dart does not have copy constructors nor have required `clone()` methods on objects, so there is no way to copy an arbitrary object, and therefore there is no way to make a deep copy of a collection of arbitrary objects.

[cameron1024's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66827315/) suggesting the use of [`package:built_value`](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) and [`package:built_collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/built_collection) is good.  If they're not suitable for you, however, you could make a function that copies elements via a callback:

```dart
List<T> copyList<T>(Iterable<T> items, T Function(T element) copier) {
  return [
    for (var item in items) copier(item),
  ];
}

class Foo {
  int i;
  String s;
  
  Foo(this.i, this.s);
  
  @override
  String toString() => 'Foo($i, "$s")';
}

void main() {
  var list = [Foo(1, 'one'), Foo(2, 'two'), Foo(3, 'three')];
  print('Original: $list');
  
  var copy = copyList<Foo>(list, (foo) => Foo(foo.i, foo.s));

  list[0].i = 100;
  print('Mutated:  $list');
  print('Copy:     $copy');
}
```